# build matrix from blocks

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have an object which is described by two quantities, A and B (in real case they can be more than two). Objects are correlated depending on the value of A and B. In particular I know the correlation matrix for A and for B. Just as example:

```
a = np.array([[1, 1, 0, 0],
              [1, 1, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 1, 1],
              [0, 0, 1, 1]])
b = np.array([[1, 1, 0],
              [1, 1, 1],
              [0, 1, 1]])
na = a.shape[0]
nb = b.shape[0]
```

correlation for A:

[image: correlation A]

so if an element has A == 0.5 and the other equal to A == 1.5 they are fully correlated (red). Otherwise if an element has A == 0.5 and the second item has A == 3.5 they are uncorrelated (blue).

Similarly for B:

[image: correlation B]

Now I want multiply the two correlation matrixes, but I want to obtain as final matrix a matrix with two axis, where the new axes are a folded version of the original axes:

```
def get_folded_bin(ia, ib):
    return ia * nb + ib
```

here what I am doing:

```
result = np.swapaxes(np.tensordot(a, b, axes=0), 1, 2).reshape(na* nb, na * nb)
```

visually:

[image]

and in particular this must hold:

```
for ia1 in xrange(na):
    for ia2 in xrange(na):
        for ib1 in xrange(nb):
            for ib2 in xrange(nb):
                assert(a[ia1, ia2] * b[ib1, ib2] == result[get_folded_bin(ia1, ib1), get_folded_bin(ia2, ib2)])
```

actually my problem is to do it with more quantities (A, B, C, ...) in a general way. Maybe there is also a simpler function within numpy to do that.

Comment: A note for other readers.  The image has origin in bottom right, where as a numeric display of `result` has it in the upper right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think finally I have found a solution:

```
np.kron(a,b)
```

and then I can compose with

```
np.kron(np.kron(a,b), c)
```

Answer (score 0):

`np.einsum` lets you simplify the `tensordot` expression a bit:

```
result = np.einsum('ij,kl->ikjl',a,b).reshape(-1, na * nb)
```

I don't think there's a way of eliminating the `reshape`.

It may also be easier to generalize to more arrays, though I wouldn't get carried away with too many iteration variables in one `einsum` expression.